# Adding own GUI in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I need to add my own, self made qt gui in paraview. I heard about paraview plugins that should allow that. But I do not find a tutorial on it. How can I add buttons, checkboxes, comboboxes in Paraview?
Could somebody show me an example? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find info on how to create checkboxes, buttons, etc? I'm doing the same and all I can find in the examples are textfields. Thanks.

Comment: After looking at a script made by someone to automatically generate GUIs (http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/534), I found that this page has the available components: http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Plugin_HowTo

Answer (score 3):

The [ParaView Wiki](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView) has lots of information on using and customising ParaView. In particular, see the section on [plugins](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView#Plugins) and the page on [writing custom applications](http://paraview.org/Wiki/Writing_Custom_Applications). These describe two different ways of customising the functionality of ParaView.

You don't state what language your GUI is written in, but if you can use or call Python then the easiest way to interact with ParaView may be through the [Python scripting interface](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python_Scripting).

Comment: I am using QT as a GUI language. As soon as I understood, you need to provide a dll. So I think (correct me if I am wrong), I should create a C++ library project in QT, create dll, lib, ... and then I should load this dll from the Paraview.

Comment: To be honest I have never tried to modify ParaView using a QT application, so I don't know any more than what is in the ParaView Wiki pages I link to. The *writing custom applications* page seems to describe the build process you need (see from [here](http://paraview.org/Wiki/Writing_Custom_Applications#How_to_write_radically_different_applications_based_on_ParaView.3F)).

Comment: I looked online at Paraview Wiki and so on, but it is a mess, it is not clear at all where should you start and where to finish..

Comment: It isn't the greatest. You're probably best off asking this question on the [ParaView users mailing list](http://www.paraview.org/paraview/help/mailing.html). The ParaView tag on SO doesn't get much attention so you are far more likely to get a definitive answer on the mailing list.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should try it there. Thanks anyway

Comment: In Paraview 4.1 it's also possible to create a plugin from a programmable filter or a programmable source (= no need to compile paraview) see http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/534

Comment: Please refer to the Examples in the paraview source code. They are up to date and you will find plugin example as well as paraview based Qt Apllication example.